# nodejs and cryptsy api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `nodejs` and `cryptsy` api.
I have the following to `.js` files (one is for the api and the other is to get the data). 
when running this command:

```
cryptsy.api('myorders', { marketid: 132 }, function (err, data) {
console.log('myorders', err ? err : data);
});
```

I am getting the following:

```
myorders [ { orderid: '331574847',
created: '2015-07-20 03:50:55',
ordertype: 'Sell',
price: '0.00000062',
quantity: '100.00000000',
orig_quantity: '100.00000000',
total: '0.00006200' } ]
```

**How can I create a function that will give me on the orderid or ordertype or any of the above options separately?**

The `cryptsy` api .js file is like this (i put it on the below link in order to avoid the code ident here. Can also be downloaded using `npm install cryptsy`):

http://textuploader.com/aa6ui

thanks